# Pandas returns unexpected result when calculate quartile from (2n+1) elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a method to calculate Interquartile range of a dataset. To do that, I first use pandas to calculate the 1st and 3rd quartile (Q1 and Q3) of that dataset. My code works when the dataset has 2n elements but failed if it has (2n+1) elements.

I'm using the following algorithm from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range#Algorithm):

> Quartiles are calculated recursively, by using median.
>
> If the number of entries is an even number 2n, then the first quartile Q1 is defined as
>
> first quartile Q1 = median of the n smallest entries
>
> and the third quartile Q3 = median of the n largest entries
>
> If the number of entries is an odd number 2n+1, then the first quartile Q1 is defined as
>
> first quartile Q1 = median of the n smallest entries
>
> and the third quartile Q3 = median of the n largest entries
>
> The second quartile Q2 is the same as the ordinary median.

This is a MCVE of my problem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])[0]
q1 = df.quantile(0.25, interpolation='midpoint') # first quartile
q3 = df.quantile(0.75, interpolation='midpoint') # third quartile
iqr = q3 - q1 # interquartile range

print(q1)
print(q3)
print(iqr)
```

The expected result:

```
1.0
3.0
2.0
```

The actual result:

```
1.5
2.5
1.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: If I change interpolation to "lower" and "higher" then the calculation will succeed for [1, 2, 3] but will fail for test case [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

The expected result:

```
1.5
4.5
3.0
```

The actual result:

```
2.0
4.0
2.0
```

Comment: Change interpolation to `lower` and `higher` instead of `midpoint`

Comment: @SreeramTP Changing interpolation to lower and higher does not seem to fix my problem, I've updated my question.

Comment: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/introduction/percentiles.html It seems that there exists different definition for 25th percentile.